# How to get record by url, insert if not found

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm doing this currently and getting an error:

> Attribute Error 'Table' object has not attribute url

```
p = session.query(pages.url == someurl).first()

if p is None:
   p = Page()
   p....
   ..
   session.add(p)
   session.commit()


SomeFunction(p)
```

I am weary if something returns null my code is going to fail, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

No, your approach is not correct, and the error is not of the 'no row' nature. From the error message, 'pages' is obviously a Table object, and not a class mapped to a table. Either you change the expression to `Pages.url==someurl` or you use `pages.c.url==someurl`, thus, specifying that you are looking for a (c) column by the name of url. Still, it is very unclear what you are trying to achieve here.